# How to add button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new in flutter.
I am following some YouTube videos to learn flutter. After adding a picture in card(home screen) now I want to add two buttons below that picture. how can i do it.

the picture Adding code

```
body: Center(
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [Image.asset("assets/image-name")],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you have a great page](https://material.io/components/buttons/flutter#contained-button), where you can find implementations of basic material widgets in Flutter.

For your example, it would look like this:

```dart
body: Center(
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image.asset("assets/image-name"),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Respond to button press
                },
              child: Text('CONTAINED BUTTON'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

For a second button, you can just add another one in the children array.
You can also wrap both buttons in [`Row`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) widget, that will allow you to place them horizontally, next to each other.